# Getting list content inside AXScrollArea

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to figure out a way to retrieve the entries in a multi-column list displayed in a scroll area.
Using the UI Element Inspector, I have found out that the window hierarchy is as `"AXApplication/AXWindow/AXScrollArea/AXScrollArea"`, but there is no more children there. The first `AXScrollArea` has a single child.

From the window, I can see there are about a 100 lines in the list.
How can I retrieve the elements?
Is there a possible alternative to retrieve the content?

I am using Applescript for now, but I have no problem in trying other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see them then it's difficult to find. Maybe it's not a cocoa application which makes it confusing. I would suggest a programmatic check. For example I can open a Finder window in list view. I can see the scroll areas also have AXOutline/AXRow/AXCell/AXTextField.

I can see the AXOutlines programmatically using:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        ui elements of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Of course then I can get "ui elements" of the outlines to dig deeper... and so on until there are no more sub-elements of what I find. Maybe you can do something similar. Good luck.

Comment: I tried this approach already, and it does not work as there is nothing shown in the UI Element Inspector. This is probably not Cocoa, which probably explains this. But then, solving the question is impossible?

Comment: You have 3 ways to script an application. 1) it has an applescript dictionary and therefore is natively apple scriptable, 2) you access menu item keyboard shortcuts by issuing keystrokes through system events, or 3) you use system events to access ui elements. So if none of those will do the job then I can't think of any other way.